# Blocking web bots with iptables

Tags: iptables

I am trying to block web bots that open up numerous connections within a short period of time.  I am using this syntax:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 20 -j logdropconnection
```

My problem is that I can't relax these parameters without iptables throwing an error.  When I try to increase the hitcount beyond 20, I get an error.  Shouldn't I be able to set that to anything I want?  For example, limit my connections to 100/second?

Answer (score 4):

Since you failed to mention the error in your question, I'll take a wild guess that `dmesg` shows this error:

`xt_recent: hitcount (100) is larger than packets to be remembered (20)`

This is a setting of the `xt_recent` (sometimes referred to as `ipt_recent`) kernel module.

You can increase the limit by updating (or creating) `/etc/modprobe.d/options.conf` with:

`options xt_recent ip_pkt_list_tot=100`

Note: this could be a problem to implement on VPS hosts with kernel-sharing features.

Comment: Indeed. I had to open a support ticket with my VPS provider to get xt_recent working on my vps.